# What is the formula that would calculate this graph?

Tags: graphing-functions

```
y = brightness in percentage
x = apparent magnitude
```

What is a formula that would result in the graph below, with y representing the brightness in percentage and x the apparent magnitude (also accounting for negative values)?

[image]

To clarify: Each decrease by 1 in apparent magnitude will require the star to have only 100/fifth root of 100 of the illumination as it used to be

Comment: If you know the relation between apparent magnitude and brightness as in your clarification, what stops you from finding the equation?

Comment: Actually, this question is wrong. A decrease of 1 is equal to the star having a (1/fifth root of 100) decrease in brightness.

Comment: Your data is pretty close.  $100^{0.2} \approx 2.511$, not far off $2.5$

Comment: I knew that it would not be much different from the actual value at low values of x, but a significant difference would be found at high values that I will extend the formula to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of [magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(astronomy)) in astronomy is that an increase of $1$ in magnitude is a factor $2.5$ reduction in brightness.  So if $m$ is the magnitude, we have
$$y=100\cdot 2.5^{1-x}$$

Comment: This still does not follow the x and y syntax in the question.

Comment: @galactic_analyzer:  it should now

Answer (score 0):

The function

$$y = -22 + 122/x$$

works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$B(M)= 250(0.4)^{M} $$

obtained by fitting $y=kb^x$ using the points $(1,100)$ and $(2,40)$